# ggplot: Creating map with discrete values, while using continuous varible

Tags: r, ggplot2

In r, I am attempting to create a map from my shapefile with will display all areas below the threshold in the color red and all areas above the threshold in the color orange. Below is my code:

```
             #First make a colour ramp

             colorramp<-c("red"<=25, "orange">25)

             #cut the data
             myshapefile$breaks <- cut(myshapefile$variable, 
                   breaks=c(0, 25, 100), 
                   labels=c("below", "above"))

             #create the map
             ggplot(myshapefile, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group))+
             geom_polygon(aes(color=myshapefile$breaks))+
             scale_fill_manual(values=colorramp, name = "Legend")
```

The breaks appear to work and are applying the correct values to the map. But the color ramp does not work. The map appears in the default red and blue colors.

How can I apply the ramp?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand without your data/shapefile. Could you post an image of what it looks like now and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have just found a solution I will post as an answer to this question.

Comment: Solution found and explained well here : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175279/how-to-create-custom-discrete-color-scheme-for-polygon-attributes-in-ggplot2